# How can I call Don Melton's transcode_video script from a shell script?

Tags: terminal, bash, automator, script

I'm trying to create a Folder Action to transcode videos using Don Melton's [scripts](https://github.com/donmelton/video_transcoding).

When I run the script, `transcode_video` complains that HandBrakeCLI is not available, but when I run the command directly from the terminal it runs fine.

[image: Screenshot of the automator action]

I'm guessing this is some kind of bash script security thing, but I'm an amateur at this game. Is there a way round this? I've had to revert to calling HandBrakeCLI directly, which is not as easy to optimise.

Comment: Do you have a link to "Don Melton's transcode video script" to help provide an answer to your question? I'd hazard a guess that the script is calling HandBrakeCLI but the shell which Automator used doesn't include that binary's directory path in its $PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Fix your path. This is as simple as adding the following as your first line. I installed the scripts through gem, not git, so transcode_video is in /usr/local/bin - you'll need to set it as appropriate.

`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"`

2. Make sure you cd into the directory you want to save the files into, as a step too. Otherwise, writes them out into $HOME, which appears to be the default working directory for automator bash scripts.

My total working code:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
for f in "$@"
do
    echo $f > /tmp/filename.txt
    cd ~/Desktop/SAmple/
    transcode-video --mp4 -v "$f" > /tmp/transcode.out
done
```